# Android - is KeyguardManager necessary to use fingerprint?

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api, keyguard

Currently implementing a fingerprint authentication following [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial) where a `KeyguardManager` is instanciated to :

> [...] verify that a backup screen unlocking method has been configured (in
>   other words a PIN or other authentication method can be used as an
>   alternative to fingerprint authentication to unlock the screen).

**Question :** I was wondering if it was really necessary to have a `KeyguardManager` to use fingerprint authentication.

Thanks,

Comment: KeyguardManager is used to check if device is secured with keyguard in fingerprint implementation , and in device itself you cant set up fingerprint without  Keyguard first you have to set it then you can add fingerprint

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know why they chose to forbid fingerprint in that case ? Why is it not possible that a protected app can be used in a unprotected phone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Fingerprint authentication in standalone mode in your app, for instance register multiple users fingerprint on same device.

When you use fingerprint authentication in your app, android check if user fingerprint match one of fingerprints register to unlock device.

Fingerprints are only register in Settings Unlock Android, your app cannot do it.